# how to implement logical query params in mongoDB (nodeJS) when you dont know the size of filter array?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

how can i implement filtering my mongoDb query when i dont know how many filters i will be using in the 'and' logical operator.

```
//Get ads from database
async function getAds() {
    return ad = await ads.Ad.find()
    .and(//filter using tags variable);
}
```

the frontend will enter an unknown amount of tags in an array called tags which looks like this

```
"Tags": ["karachi","lahore"]
```

the problem is i dont know how many elements in tags variable will be, which the front end will give me using query params. any help would be appreciated. How can i seperately write all these tags in and operator when i dont know how many will there be in that array.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you want the following...

```
async function getAds() {
    return ad = await ads.Ad.find({ "Tags": { $in: [ "karachi", "lahore" ] } });
}
```

Comment: Doesnt this statement act as an OR logical query rather than an AND which i need in this case. I want both of those tags to be there in order to show up in the query not any one of the tags.

Comment: So i think the answer to this is the $all operator which acts as an AND statement. Thankyou for your help

Comment: Yes, $in is an OR condition whereas $all is an AND condition